# undefined is not an object (evaluating 'app.options.databaseURL')

Tags: firebase, react-native

For some reason I have been getting this error a lot and i am not sure what's the cause of it. I am creating an app using react native that utilized the same firebase as database for my website as well. For now the goal is to reading data from the firebase and I am not sure if I am declaring or calling any functions wrong since I am still new to this so not sure, what's triggering this error.

```
import React from 'react';
import { 
    View,
    Text,
    TouchableOpacity,
    SafeAreaView
} from 'react-native';
import * as firebase from 'firebase'
import {config} from '../config/FirebaseAuth'

if (!firebase.apps.length) {
    firebase.initializeApp(config);
}



class AccountScreen extends React.Component {


    constructor (props) {   
        super(props); 
        this.state = {
            myItemsReference: null
        }; 
    }
    componentDidMount(){
    
        const myitems = firebase.database().ref("Item")
        myitems.on("value", datasnap => {
            console.log('database Worked!!!', datasnap.val());
        });
        this.setState({myItemsReference: myitems});
    }
    componentWillUnmount(){
        if(this.state.myItemsReference) {
            myItemsReference.off("value");
        }
    }



    render() {
        return(
            <SafeAreaView>
                <View>
                    <Text> Hello</Text> 
                </View>
            </SafeAreaView>
        );
    }
}
export default AccountScreen;
```

the file FirebaseAuth this is what it contains:

```
export const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: xxxxxx,
    authDomain: xxxxxxx,
    databaseURL: xxxxxx,
    projectId: xxxxxxx,
    storageBucket: xxxxxxxxxx,
    messagingSenderId: xxxxxxxxx,
    appId: xxxxxxxx,
    measurementId: xxxxxx
  };
```

Comment: Please include the relevant part of `'../config/FirebaseAuth'` (making sure to hide the important details)

Comment: sorry about that I have include the content of firebaseAuth

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `../config/FirebaseAuth` is exactly as you posted it, this is a pretty simple problem.

On this line you import the `config` variable from `../config/FirebaseAuth` — which doesn't exist!

```
import {config} from '../config/FirebaseAuth'
// config is undefined

if (!firebase.apps.length) {
    firebase.initializeApp(); // effectively does this (no databaseURL field!)
}
```

So to fix this, you either need to import `firebaseConfig` as `config` or update each time you use `config` to `firebaseConfig`.

```
import {firebaseConfig as config} from '../config/FirebaseAuth'
// config is { apiKey: xxxxxx, ... }

if (!firebase.apps.length) {
    firebase.initializeApp(config);
}
```

or

```
import {firebaseConfig} from '../config/FirebaseAuth'
// firebaseConfig is { apiKey: xxxxxx, ... }

if (!firebase.apps.length) {
    firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
}
```

Comment: @Debuggingnightmare If this solved your problem, don't forget to close it by accepting the answer.